# How to split text based on <span></span> tags -Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string, its value is

```
"Your <span data-schedule="departureAirportCode"></span> <span class="icon icon> </span> <span class="alt">to</span>"
```

and I need to split these based on starting and closing span tags and need the final output should be

```
var newArray=[<span data-schedule="departureAirportCode"></span>,<span class="icon icon> </span>,span class="alt">to</span>]
```

Any help will be highly helpful and thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for contributing to SO. Please take some time to read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question will likely be met with some backlash because it seems you haven't done anything to solve this problem yourself, but rather are just asking us to write code for you. If that isn't the case, please edit your question to show your attempts and/or research. We're happy to let you know where you went wrong and what can be done to remedy your mistake(s), but first, you need to *help us* help you.

Comment: As a helpful nudge, if you fixed your string (currently it isn't valid. You should encapsulate it with single quotes `'` instead of double quotes, and your `<span class="icon icon` doesn't have a closing `"`) and populated an element with it (`$("<div />").html(myString)`, for example), you could then do a simple `.children("span").toArray()` on it, and it would return exactly what you're requesting.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you'll have to correct some typos in your string:

- Encapsulate the string with `'` instead of `"`, or escape the `"`s, or use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
- Close the `"` in your `<span class="icon icon` (Side note: Why the same class twice?)

After you've got a valid HTML string, throwing it into a container will allow you to manipulate and parse it with ease. Fetching the spans and using a [jQuery `.toArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/toArray/) would return the output you're expecting.

```js
var str = 'Your <span data-schedule="departureAirportCode"></span> <span class="icon"> </span> <span class="alt">to</span>'

var arr = $("<div />")           //Create a container for the HTML string
              .html(str)         //Populate it with the HTML
              .children("span")  //Find the <span> elements
              .toArray();        //Return them as an array

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```